# How to convert an existing A4 PDF document to an A5 booklet?

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to implement A4 pdf to A5 booklet format pdf using itext but its not converting as per A5 format. Anyone suggest how to do, which will be great helpful.

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest)
        throws IOException, DocumentException {
    // Creating a reader
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    // step 1
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A5.rotate());
    // step 2
    PdfWriter writer
            = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
    float a4_width = PageSize.A4.getWidth();
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    int p = 0;
    PdfImportedPage page;
    while (p++ < n) {
        page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, p);
        if (p % 2 == 1) {
            canvas.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
        } else {
            canvas.addTemplate(page, a4_width, 0);
            document.newPage();
        }
    }
    // step 5
    document.close();
    reader.close();
}
```

Comment: Please describe the problem. You are creating an A5 document here: `Document document = new Document(PageSize.A5.rotate());` and you are adding pages to this document. However, these pages might not display at the expected place if the original pages aren't standard. Also: due to the nature of the operation, all interactive features will be lost. Please clarify which of the above problems you are experiencing.

Comment: Thanks Bruno for reply, My requirement is need to create a A5 format booklet . PDF may contains 200 0r 300 pages all those to be converted as A5 booklet format. what are the changes need to done to display in exact position for above program.

Comment: Also I am sharing the sample A3 booklet PDF. This A3 booklet pdf is converted from A4 pdf using itext program. In the same way need to convert A4 to A5 booklet.  Kindly check this link:  A4 to A3 booklet https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VpRB8oS2cpWItdRiJ2WAgpMv_fIVGv8Q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Aha, now I understand the problem: you forgot to scale down the pages. (For a moment I confused A3 with A5, and so did you.) So the answer to your question is very simple: you can fix the problem by scaling down the imported pages.

Comment: Please help on this, how to scaling down the imported pages.

Comment: It's just a matter of adding some extra parameters to the `addTemplate()` method. I'm assuming that you've studied sufficient Math at school to calculate the value of those parameters. In any case: I have another job to do right now.

Comment: ok bruno, i will try